# Which type of ip address is "2405:204:a581:e021:995b:368e:9b00:ddd5"?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I get the ip address. when user register on my app the web services are written in php IP address is "2405:204:a581:e021:995b:368e:9b00:ddd5" so how can I change into normal ip address

Comment: It looks like an IPV6 address. Things are moving towards IPV6 so I would get used to these kind of addresses rather than trying to make them into IPV4 addresses

Comment: so can i get the user location through this ipaddress

Comment: You can read about the differences between IPv4 and IPv6 here: https://techlog360.com/ipv4-vs-ipv6/

Comment: IPV4 is basically being phased out. Get used to IPV6 it will soon be the norm

Comment: i wanna get the location of user through ipadress so how can i do that. through this ip

Comment: There is not link between IPV6 address and Location. The fact that IPV4 had a link was purely accidental in reality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162675/geolocation-with-ipv6

Comment: @RiggsFolly ` ... it will soon ` ! funny, one of my network engineers told me the same in 1996 !

Comment: Thanks to every one

Answer (score 4):

This is an IPv6 adress. It cannot be transfered to IPv4.